# The CommandText property has not been properly initialized error when Transactionalized

Tags: c#, mysql

This code had previously been working fine. I need to transactionalize my read writes however, and when trying to begin that process by transactionalizing my read, I've ran into this commandText uninitialized error.

Exact Error, Line 156 is  `DA.Fill(tbl);`

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The CommandText property has not been properly initialized.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at MDB_N2000.DatabaseManager.GetTable(TableQuery query) in C:\Users\Tcordeau.pub\DocumentsException thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MySql.Data.dll
\MDB-N2000\MDB-N2000\Model\DatabaseManager.cs:line 156 The CommandText property has not been properly initialized.
```

1. Call LoadTable.

   ```
   public void LoadTable()
   {
       if (Db.IsConnOpen)
       {
           Db.BeginTransaction();
           // Persist the selected row across table reload by keeping track of the row's first value.
           // For this to work, tables need to always have an autonumbered integer index in the first column.
           // Store the row index.
           if (Vals.Any())
               if (Vals[0].Val != null)
                   if (Vals[0].Val.GetType() == typeof(int))
                       RowID = Vals[0].Val;

           // For tables in the sub-tables viewer, get the key value of the main table of the module
           // to use as a parameter in the SQL select query.
           if (!IsMainTable)
           {
               LoadTableQuery.Prms[0].Val = MainVM.Modules.SelectedModule.Vwr.Table.Vals[0].Val;
           }

           // Get the table from the database
           Tbl = Db.GetTable(LoadTableQuery);
           DataTable MainTable = Db.GetTable(LoadTableQuery);
           MainTable.TableName = "MainTable";
           dv.Table = MainTable;

           // Retrieve the row index and set the selected row.
           if (Vals.Any())
               if (Vals[0].Val != null)
                   if (Vals[0].Val.GetType() == typeof(int))
                       Tbl.DefaultView.Sort = Tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
           //SelectedRowIndex = Tbl.DefaultView.Find(RowID);
           Db.CommitTransaction();
       }
   }
   ```
2. goes to GetTable.

   ```
   public DataTable GetTable(TableQuery query)
   {
       DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
       if (IsConnOpen)
       {
           try
           {
               SelectCmd.Parameters.Clear();
               SelectCmd.CommandText = query.Qry;
               for (int i = 0; i < query.Prms.Count; i++)
               {
                   SelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(query.Prms[i].Col, query.Prms[i].Val);
               }
               // DA = MySQLDataAdapter
               DA.Fill(tbl);
               tbl.DefaultView.Sort = tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString() + " ASC";

           }
           catch (MySqlException ex)
           {
               Msg = "Error: " + ex.Number + " " + ex.Message + " from Qry = " + query.Qry;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Msg = "Error: " + ex + " " + ex.Message;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           Msg = "Not Connected";
       }
       return tbl;
   }
   ```

I've printed the query to console before to make sure it's not blank.

**reference methods.**

```
    private DatabaseManager()
    {
        Acct = new Account();

        SelectCmd = new MySqlCommand() { Connection = Conn };
        UpdateCmd = new MySqlCommand() { Connection = Conn };
        Cmd = new MySqlCommand() { Connection = Conn };
        DA = new MySqlDataAdapter(SelectCmd)
        {
            UpdateCommand = UpdateCmd
        };

        Msg = "Ready to Connect";
    }

    // Creates a new transaction and returns the command it's attached to.
    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        SelectCmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
        MySqlTransaction NewTransaction = Conn.BeginTransaction();
        SelectCmd.Connection = Conn;
        SelectCmd.Transaction = NewTransaction;
    }

    //rollsback transaction
    public void RevertTransaction()
    {
        Cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
    }

    //adds a query to the transaction
    public void TransactionQuery(TableQuery NewQuery)
    {
        Cmd.CommandText = NewQuery.Qry;
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    //commits transaction
    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        SelectCmd.Transaction.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error and what is the *exact* text of the error?

Comment: @RonBeyer Updated with the error message, and where it's being generated.

Comment: You create the `DA` in the `DatabaseManager` constructor and set the update command, but you never set the select command. It isn't associated with `DA`, so it has no select command to run, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem / solution was to remove this line

```
public void BeginTransaction()
{
   // SelectCmd = Conn.CreateCommand();  //Problem Line
    MySqlTransaction NewTransaction = Conn.BeginTransaction();
    SelectCmd.Connection = Conn;
    SelectCmd.Transaction = NewTransaction;
}
```